# Natbib numbering problem

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I have to use natbib for a conference paper bibliography and I'm having trouble getting the numbering working. I have the following code:

```
...
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
...
\begin{document}
...
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{FAR_citations}
\end{document}
```

With the following in `FAR_citations.bib`:

```
@ONLINE {spy_camera,
    author = "Adafruit",
    title  = "Spy Camera for Raspberry Pi",
    year   = "2015",
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.adafruit.com/products/1937}}
}

@ONLINE {raspberry_pi,
    author = "Adafruit",
    title  = "Raspberry Pi Model B+ 512MB RAM",
    year   = "2015",
    howpublished = {\url{http://www.adafruit.com/products/1914}}
}

@ONLINE {powerboost,
    author = "Adafruit",
    title  = "PowerBoost 500 Basic - 5V USB Boost at 500mA from 1.8V+",
    year   = "2015",
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.adafruit.com/products/1903}}
}
```

The output is:

[image]

The following are my problems:

1. How do I make natbib sort the order of the citations by their order of appearance in the document?
2. How do I make natbib put [1], [2], etc. instead of these weird [Ada15a], [Ada15b] type citations?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: This code produces the right output for me: 
`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\cite{raspberry_pi,powerboost,spy_camera}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{FAR_citations}
\end{document}`

Comment: Your screenshot strongly suggests that you (a) were using the `alpha` bibliography style (or something very similar) prior to switching to `unsrtnat` and (b) have not (or, not yet) re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more, which is needed to fully propagate all changes. Try recompiling your document in the manner described in the preceding sentence.

Comment: Okay, I actually created a new latex project and copy pasted everything over and now, magically, is works. I was indeed using alpha prior to switching to unsrsat... however commenting out alpha changed nothing - and perhaps TeXlipse (what I use) was not doing the compilation properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot and description you've posted give the impression that you used to work with the `alpha` citation call-out style (probably achieved by specifying the bibliography style `alpha`, or something very similar) before switching over to an unsorted numeric call-out style, to be achieved by (a) using the `unsrtnat` bibliography style and (b) loading the `natbib` citation management package with the option `numbers`.

After switching bibliography styles, it is mandatory to recompile the document with LaTeX, re-run BibTeX, and then re-run LaTeX *twice more* in order to propagate all changes. Did you remember to run this four-step process?

Two additional comments/suggestions:

- The entry type `@online` is not actually defined by either the `unsrtnat` or the `alpha` bibliography style. In such cases, BibTeX falls back on the catch-all entry type `@misc` to format the entries. The `@misc` entry type recognizes and knows how to process the field named `howpublished`.
- Be sure to prevent BibTeX from lowercasing uppercase-letter acronyms -- such as `USB`, `RAM`, and `MB` -- that occur in the `title` fields of your entries. The easiest way to achieve this is to encase the contents of the `title` fields in curly braces.

Here's a modified version of your code that achieves your stated objectives and also preserves uppercase spelling of words in the `title` fields.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{FAR_citations.bib}
@ONLINE {spy_camera,
    author = "Adafruit",
    title  = "Spy Camera for {Raspberry Pi}",
    year   = "2015",
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.adafruit.com/products/1937}},
}

@ONLINE {raspberry_pi,
    author = "Adafruit",
    title  = "{Raspberry Pi Model B+ 512MB RAM}",
    year   = "2015",
    howpublished = {\url{http://www.adafruit.com/products/1914}},
}

@ONLINE {powerboost,
    author = "Adafruit",
    title  = "{PowerBoost 500 Basic---5V USB Boost at 500mA from 1.8V+}",
    year   = "2015",
    howpublished = {\url{https://www.adafruit.com/products/1903}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{powerboost}, \cite{raspberry_pi}, and \cite{spy_camera}.
\bibliography{FAR_citations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, really appreciate this help!